# Unable to find provider assembly with name Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I created an ASP.Net Core API project in VS 2017 and Added .Net Core Class library. Then I installed following nuggets inside the class library. (i need to use this class library as a DAL)

> Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql
>
> Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Design

I have an existing database. so i need to generate ModelClasses using Database first approach.

So I executed the following command in the package manager console (Web API project name is Test & Class Library name is DAL). I set the DAL as my default project in the package manager console

> dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold
> "server=localhost;port=3306;user=root;password=abc123;database=test;"
> Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql -o Models -p DAL -s Test

after executing this command im getting following error.

```
Unable to find provider assembly with name Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql. Ensure the specified name is correct and is referenced by the project.
```

I tried to find a solution for this and I was unable to find it. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Have you set your default project in Package Manager Console to your class library?

Comment: yes. i have set it

Comment: does your class library successfully build?

Comment: Yes. The class library successfully builds

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue using Visual Studio 2019 (version 16.6.0), ASP.NET Core 3.1, EF Core, and Pomelo, all installed using Package Manager.

Trying to scaffold a database would remove Pomelo from my references.  After some googling I found a reference to update Visual Studio, which I did to version 16.6.2 which corrected the issue.  (Sorry can't remember the link with reason for update).  It seemed like it had something to do with a package referencing an earlier .net version of something? but can't rember.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading the .net Core version 2.1.1 to 2.2.0 it works properly.